# If I create a class in Scala, does it implicitly extends AnyVal, AnyRef or both?

Tags: scala, class, hierarchy

If I write a class in Scala, does it automatically extends AnyVal, AnyRef or both?

Answer (score 1):

> If I write a class in Scala, does it automatically extends AnyVal, AnyRef or both?

It should be obvious that it cannot automatically extend both because a Scala class can only extend one class, not two.

It should also be obvious that it cannot automatically extend `AnyVal` because classes that extend [`AnyVal`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.1/scala/AnyVal.html) must [obey some specific restrictions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) which cannot, in general, be satisfied by any random class.

Therefore, the only sensible way it *could* work is that a class automatically extends [`AnyRef`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.1/scala/AnyRef.html).

However, we don't have to use common sense, we don't have to use our brains at all, we can just look into the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-definitions) [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## 5.3 *Class Definitions*
>
> The extends clause `extends sc with mt_1 with … with mt_m` can be omitted, in which case **`extends scala.AnyRef`** is assumed.

Comment: Thanks! But if Scala supports only single inheritance,  how come Null and Nothing can extend more than one class? Here's an image of Scala hierarchy: https://docs.scala-lang.org/resources/images/tour/unified-types-diagram.svg

Comment: That sounds like an interesting question, which should go into a question, not in a comment. The short answer is: they don't extend more than one class. They are subtypes of every other type, but not subclasses.